# How to select checkboxes in row in react-virtuaized Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, semantic-ui-react, react-virtualized

I have implemented a Table using the react-virtualized Table component. I have added a checkbox column in the table and now want to implement the select all/select row functionality using those checkboxes.

Now, for adding select all/select row functionality, I am using react hooks for changing the `checked` prop of `CheckBox` but it doesn't seem to work. Below is the code link and when I scroll down the page with actual data, the checkbox checked state is removed.

Here's the code that I am trying to do, `checked` is always remaining false for rows except for the header. Header select all is functioning fine

```
...
import {Checkbox} from 'semantic-ui-react';
const[selectAll, setSelectAll] = useState(false):
const checked = [];
function _checkboxState(data) {
    if (checked.includes(data.index)) {
      checked.pop(data.index);
    } else {
      checked.push(data.index);
    }
  }
<Column
    disableSort
    dataKey="checkbox"
    width={30}
    headerRenderer={() => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={selectAll}
        onChange={() => {
          if (selectAll === true) {
            setSelectAll(false);
          } else {
            setSelectAll(true);
          }
        }}
      />
    )}
    cellRenderer={({rowIndex}) => (
      <Checkbox
        checked={selectAll || checked.includes(rowIndex)}
        onChange={(e, data) => {
          _checkboxState(data);
        }}
        index={rowIndex}
      />
    )}
/>
...
```

1. How to maintain the checks after even scrolling the table?
2. Where I am doing wrong for checking individual rows?

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the meantime, while I was waiting for an answer, I spent more time and found that I was mutating `checked` and not using `useState` hook.

This is the updated code:

```
.....
const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

const _onChangeHeaderCheckbox = data => {
    data.checked ? setChecked(sortedList.map(row => row.id)) : setChecked([]);
  };

const _onChangeRowCheckbox = data => {
    const newRow = sortedList[data.index].id;
    checked.includes(newRow)
      ? setChecked(old => old.filter(row => row !== newRow))
      : setChecked(old => [...old, newRow]);
  };

....
<Column
  disableSort
  dataKey="checkbox"
  width={30}
  headerRenderer={() => (
    <Checkbox
      indeterminate={
        checked.length > 0 && checked.length < sortedList.length
      }
      checked={checked.length === sortedList.length}
      onChange={(e, data) => _onChangeHeaderCheckbox(data)}
    />
  )}
  cellRenderer={({ rowIndex }) => (
    <Checkbox
      checked={checked.includes(sortedList[rowIndex].id) === true}
      onChange={(e, data) => _onChangeRowCheckbox(data)}
      index={rowIndex}
    />
  )}
/>
....
```

Here's the working preview with dummy data:

[image: Edit react-virtualized table checbox stackoverflow]